# 2 factor authentication on Windows Server 2019

Tags: authentication, windows-server

I would like to harden my Windows Server 2019 a bit.

I want to add 2 factor authentication for users that log in locally on my Windows Server 2019.
When the user log in I want the second authentication to be something like this (in order of prority)

1. Push request to iPhone mobile app or key from Google
   Authenticator
2. Fallback to text message with the code
3. Fallback to automated call telling me the code

The main thread I want to gard against is a keylogger on the keyboard, but there might be other ways to hack into the system.

I have also encrypted the disks.

Maybe I can setup an [Azure multi-factor authentication server](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/pricing/details/multi-factor-authentication/) but would prefer something a bit cheaper and simpler give this is only for one server. Something along [these](https://download.microsoft.com/download/6/5/8/6587B418-75B1-4FCB-84D4-984BC479309E/JuniperPulse_Azure_MFA_LDAP.docx) lines.

Comment: Windows doesn’t have support to send out an SMS message, but it can be configured to support 2FA, having difficulty determining what your question is exactly

Comment: @Ramhound Yes, enable 2FA for local users on the server. There is no AD.